# Is there an ATM in the international transit area in the Auckland (AKL) airport?

Tags: airports, money, exchange, airport-terminals, akl

I will be traveling from the US to Sydney soon. I'm flying Air New Zealand, and my flight requires me to change planes in Auckland. Both the arriving and the departing flights are at Terminal I. There is only an hour and a quarter between flights.

I need to take a specific amount of cash in New Zealand dollars to Australia with me. Is there an ATM I could use in the international transit area for this? Almost certainly there isn't enough time to pass through security, so I'm hoping that there is some cash machine I can use in Terminal I that is past the checkpoint.

Comment: I assume Terminal I is the international terminal? The [airport maps](https://www.aucklandairport.co.nz/information/airport-maps) don't show an ATM after the security check, but there is an exchange bureau, so you can bring US dollars and exchange them there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Official" [airport maps](https://www.aucklandairport.co.nz/information/airport-maps) suggest one ATM **outside** the gate area on the ground floor.  Several exchange desks on both floors; ground floor, **nothing** inside the gate area; top floor, three exchange desks inside the gate area.

Comment: Yes, as you and @martin.koeberl saw on the maps, there isn’t any ATM in the transit area.